# Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample

Tags: java, jdbc, javabeans

Here is the complete error:

Unable to connect. Cannot establish a connection to jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/sample using org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver (The connection was refused because the database sample was not found.).

I am following the steps in this tutorial to create a DB, as I am teaching myself this to help a friend build a website.  So learning as I go here.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TNXn5jW95MU

I already tried to create the "sample" file, but it says it already exists, so it is there.  Have no idea what to do here.

Comment: You may be missing some server configuration in your server's administration console, or elsewhere

Comment: I am learning this from scratch here so would you be able to tell me how to adjust that configuration?

Comment: I couldn't say that's the error for sure, but usually when I have trouble accessing a database I haven't specified communication between the server and database correctly. You'll have to figure out how your db is configured on your particular server, and how to access your server's administration console to make the changes.

Comment: Found the admin console but it is all foreign to me, just a simple coder and config and network setting like this go over my head.

Comment: Sorry, short of doing your research for you I couldn't give you a specific answer, which is why your question hasn't been answered quickly. You'll have to commit some time to understanding how to configure a derby server correctly or find someone to help you in meat-space. The good news is, you'll learn a lot if you manage to solve this issue on your own.

Comment: Yeah I am already researching it.  Thanks for helping, it is appreciated and got me looking in the right direction.